# Permission denied to clone angular-mock from git

Tags: git, github, bower, bower-install, angular-mock

I'm using angular-mock in bower and when I do bower install, I'm getting following error:

> ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads
>   https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git", exit code of #128
>   Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and
>   the repository exists.
>
> Additional error details: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could
>   not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I had pointed to SSH instead of HTTPS call to github.com, I have deleted following line in git .config file and got resolved

> [url "git@github.com"]
>     insteadOf = https://github.com/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you dont have ssh-key setup.

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

#### Generate ssh-keys (if you dont have any)

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)

Comment: But why we should add SSH to clone angular-mocks? It is a public repo, and I'm hitting it by HTTPS not by git.(SSH).